# CriteriaQuery Joining entities in Hibernate single table inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, criteriaquery

I am facing an issue while trying to perform a join involving entities in a Hibernate Single Table Inheritance scenario. I have two entities: VehicleEntity (base class) and CarriageEntity (subclass with discriminator value "CARRIAGE").

```java
// VehicleEntity
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "vehicle_type_id", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class VehicleEntity {
    // ... (fields and annotations)
}

// CarriageEntity
@Entity
@Data
@DiscriminatorValue("CARRIAGE")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class CarriageEntity extends VehicleEntity {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private PassengerDataEntity passengerData;
}
```

I am attempting to join VehicleEntity with CarriageEntity using the passengerData field, which exists only in CarriageEntity. However, my current approach is resulting in the error:

```
Unable to locate Attribute with the given name [passengerData] on this ManagedType [es.adif.sit.reg.rollingstock.access.model.VehicleEntity]
```

Here's a simplified version of the code where the error is occurring:

```java
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cQ = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<VehicleEntity> vehicle = cQ.from(VehicleEntity.class);
Join<VehicleEntity, CarriageEntity> carriage = vehicle.join("passengerData");
```

I've tried various approaches, including using treat and JoinType.LEFT, but I haven't been successful. How can I properly join VehicleEntity and CarriageEntity when the join involves a field that exists only in the subclass?

Any insights or examples on how to perform this type of join correctly would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Vehicle doesn't have a "passengerData" reference to CarriageEntity, which is what your join looks setup to handle. What you want is to "treat" the Vehicle root as a CarriageEntity to allow you to then join to the PassengerDataEntity passengerData "cb.treat(vehicle, CarriageEntity.class).join("passengerData")". But since you are performing a join, why not just query on the CarriageEntity directly instead of VehicleEntity?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, Chris. The provided example is a minified version. I have four classes that inherit from VehicleEntity, and I need to retrieve instances of all these classes using the same method simultaneously. That's why I'm using the parent class (VehicleEntity) as the root. Up until now, I've been filtering based on the fields common to all classes (the fields in VehicleEntity). However, I now need to filter based on attributes specific to the inherited classes. I'm going to try the suggested solution. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Chris,

Generally, your solution works fine. However, when I attempt to retrieve data using a field of an inherited class, the results of all queries are limited to only the inherited class. For example, if I filter by getting all the Wagons and then use an OR condition to retrieve the Carriages whose passenger data is X, it only retrieves CarriageEntities from the database, excluding other inherited classes from VehicleEntity. The filters without treats over the inherited classes are working fine. Do you have any ideas on how to overcome this?

Thank you!

Comment: Show what you tried, as the spec states it should work. It gives an example (section  4.4.9) "WHERE TREAT(p AS LargeProject).budget > 1000
      OR TREAT(p AS SmallProject).name LIKE 'Persist%'"